# Gradle mavenDeployer override artifact version command line

Tags: maven, gradle

I use gradle to upload built artifacts to our repository manager (Nexus).
I'm using the following command line:

```
./gradlew --stacktrace --info uploadArchives -PnexusUsername=de -PnexusPassword=np
```

In the build.gradle file, I have:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/releases") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I override the default version from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick way to support this.
In the build.gradle, I added and updated `uploadArchives`:

```
...
version = getVersion()

// Option to override Nexus version by setting env var CUSTOM_VERSION
def pomVersion = System.getenv("CUSTOM_VERSION") ?: version
...
...

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/releases") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.version = pomVersion
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I just need to set **CUSTOM_VERSION** before running the command line.

I hope this helps. More options are welcome!